# Getdown launch single instance java GUI

Tags: java, swing, javafx, singleton, jnlp

I am using Getdown to launch javafx and or java swing applications.

I would like to have a Single instance capability.
Such when there is an instance running. You cannot open another one. Therefore only single instance is allowed.

How you would I achieve this ? Am currently using java 11 for javafx GUI.

Getdown is system for deploying Java applications to end-user computers, which is designed as a replacement for Java Web Start.

JNLP offers a SingleInstanceListener. How can I do the same with Getdown?

https://github.com/threerings/getdown

Comment: An application singleton is often achieved one of two ways. 1) Check for a particular socket on launch and open it if free. Close it on exit. 2) (Similarly) Create a temporary file and delete it on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Getdown, so apologies if this is not applicable.

If you are only using Windows and JNA is acceptable, this code works like a charm. I have been using it for decades via many different languages.

When the app starts:

```
mutex = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateMutex(null, true, mutexName);
if (Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError() == WinError.ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
  System.exit(-1);
}
```

Then when the app closed:

```
Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReleaseMutex(mutex);
Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(mutex);
```